# Space complexity of first non-repeating character algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, space-complexity

The following algorithm I wrote finds the first non-repeating character in a string and returns its index or -1 if there are none:

```
def firstNonRepeatingCharacter(string):
    stack = []
    repeats = []
    for char in string:
        if char in stack:
            del stack[stack.index(char)]
            repeats.append(char)
        elif char not in stack and char not in repeats:
            stack.append(char)
    if len(stack) > 0:
        return string.index(stack[0])
    return -1
```

Would its space complexity be O(1) since you can have O(26) elements in either the stack or repeat lists, but not both?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your variable called `stack` is **not** a stack, and the operations `if char in stack: del stack[stack.index(char)]` are not particularly efficient. Instead, you could for instance use a `dict`, mapping each alphabet character to the index of its first occurrence in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, additional `space complexity` consumed by your program is `O(1)`, because data structures can include at most 26 elements regardless of the input size.

And again, your `time complexity` will be `O(n)`, not `O(n^2)` due to the inner loops.

```py
for char in string:   # O(n) - n being the number of characters in your string
   if char in stack:  # O(1) since stack can have at most 26 characters
      del stack[stack.index(char)] 
      repeats.append(char)
   elif char not in stack and char not in repeats:  # O(1) since stack and repeats can have at most 26 characters
      stack.append(char)
   if len(stack) > 0:
      return string.index(stack[0])
```

As stated in the comment, your variable named as stack is not actually a `stack` and some of the operations seem redundant. You can implement the same process more efficiently using a `dict`.

```py
def firstNonRepeatingCharacter(string):
    dict_ = {}
    for idx in range(len(string)):   # n many iterations
        char = string.lower()[idx]
        dict_[char] = len(string) if (char in dict_) else idx
    
    idx = min(dict_.values()) # dict_ can have at most 26 elements - O(1)
    return -1 if(idx == len(string)) else idx

firstNonRepeatingCharacter("aabc")
```

Remember that `x in dict` operation takes `O(1)` in average due to the hash function used. Also length of the dictionary can be at most 26, number of characters in the alphabet.